# How to return only array of employeeID without request status details

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on the Blazor server side, I face an issue when returning data from web API.

My issue is I can't return an array of objects with `employeeID` without the request details.

I need to return only an array of object `employeeID` and without these request status details:

> id, exception, status, isCanceled, isCompleted, isCompletedSuccessfully, creationOptions, asyncState, isFaulted

So how to return only the array of objects of `employeeID` as mentioned above?

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAllEmployee/{searchText}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllEmployee(string searchText)
{

    string query = "";


    query = "SELECT cast(EMP.YAAN8 as varchar(20)) as EmployeeID,EMP.YAALPH AS EmployeeName FROM CRPDTA.F060116 EMP WHERE cast(EMP.YAAN8 as varchar(20)) LIKE '%" + searchText + "%' WITH UR";


    try
    {
        ICollection<object> ApplicationsDataValues = new List<object>();
        using (var command = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            await command.Connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    ApplicationsDataValues.Add(new
                    {
                        EmployeeID = reader.GetFieldValueAsync<string>(0)


                    });
                }
            }
        }
        await  con.CloseAsync();
        return StatusCode(200, ApplicationsDataValues); // Get all users   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e);
    }

}
```

The current result returned:

```
[
    {
        "employeeID": {
            "result": "212334",
            "id": 251,
            "exception": null,
            "status": 5,
            "isCanceled": false,
            "isCompleted": true,
            "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
            "creationOptions": 0,
            "asyncState": null,
            "isFaulted": false
        }
    },
    {
        "employeeID": {
            "result": "212331",
            "id": 252,
            "exception": null,
            "status": 5,
            "isCanceled": false,
            "isCompleted": true,
            "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
            "creationOptions": 0,
            "asyncState": null,
            "isFaulted": false
        }
    }
]
```

The expected result returned:

```cs
[
    {
        "employeeID": "212334"
    },
    {
        "employeeID": "212331"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GetFieldValueAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfieldvalueasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) method returns the value of `Task<T>`. You need to apply the `await` to get the value.

```cs
ApplicationsDataValues.Add(new
{
    EmployeeID = await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<string>(0)
});
```

Alternatively, you may look for the [`GetFieldValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfieldvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) method to get the value.

```cs
ApplicationsDataValues.Add(new
{
    EmployeeID = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(0)
});
```